# trouble of getting out to

Tags: meaning-in-context

Help me please about the exact meaning of the following passage. The words in bold are intended.

"Although the SD had taken the trouble of getting Mayr and Gamotha out to Persia, and although war with Russia had broken out, Berlin was so confident of victory farther west that it did not see any reason for organizing espionage."

Many thanks in advance.

meaning-in-context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this context, "take the trouble of getting out" means to make the effort of getting Mayr and Gamotha to Persia. The "getting to" implies transfering/guiding/taking someone to the location, and it is not part of the idiom "take the trouble", as evidentiated by:  [thefreedictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/take+the+trouble)